# why can I inject a repo to the H2 trigger bean

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, h2

I want to inject the repo to a trigger bean to operate some logic when the some insert happens.

DI dose not work here. but it worked anywhere else.

When debug ,the injected Repo referes NULL.

It will throw exception when inject through constructor because of the null value.

I also placed @Order to control the priority of bean creating, that doesn't work though.

code like this:

```
@Component
public class MyTrigger implements Trigger {

    @Autowired
    TableTestRepo tableTestRepo;

    @Override
    public void init(Connection connection, String s, String s1, String s2, boolean b, int i) throws SQLException {
        Trigger.super.init(connection, s, s1, s2, b, i);
    }

    @Override
    public void fire(Connection connection, Object[] objects, Object[] objects1) throws SQLException {
        //logic
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        Trigger.super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() throws SQLException {
        Trigger.super.remove();
    }
}


@Repository
public interface TableTestRepo extends JpaRepository<TableTestEntity,Long> {

}
```

why and how to work around

Comment: So you refuse to show the not-working-code where you inject the Repo via Constructor as well as providing the full Exception? How do you think anyone can help this way?

Comment: I supporse there are all related codes. when debug ,the injected Repo referes NULL. DI is as easy as the basic idea of spring framework, but is not worked here. I also placed @Order to control the priority of bean creating, that doesn't work though.